# Small question about convergence of probalility

Tags: probability-theory

In the lecture our professor mentioned that: If $X_1 , X_2, ...$ are iid random variables. Then
$ n P (|X_1| \ge a_n) \to 0$ implies $ P(\max _{k \le n} |X_k| > a_n) \to 0$, where $\{a_n\}$ is just a sequence of real numbers.

But I have trouble to see this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not use the independence since $P(\max _{k \leqslant n} |X_k| > a_n)$ is
$$ 
P\left(\bigcup_{k \leqslant n}\{ |X_k| > a_n\}\right)\leqslant\sum_{k\leqslant n} P (|X_k|> a_n)=nP(|X_1|> a_n)\leqslant nP(|X_1|\leqslant a_n)$$